# Using SQL how can I write a query to find the top 5 per category per month?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to get the Top 5 rows with the highest number for each category for a specific time interval such as a month. What I currently have returns 5 of the exact same descriptions for a category. I am trying to get the top five. This only happens when I try to sort it based on a time period.

```
WITH CustomerRank
AS
(SELECT 
    Count(*) AS "Count",
    d.Item,
    d.Description,
    Name,
    i.Type,
    d.CreatedOn    
FROM [dbo].i,
    d,
    dbo.b,
    as,
    a,
    c
WHERE d.Inspection_Id = i.Id  AND d.Inspection_Id = i.Id AND 
    b.Id = i.BuildingPart_Id AND b.as= Assessments.Id
    AND as.Application_Id = a.Id AND a.Customer_Id = Customers.Id                                
group by d.Item, d.Description, Name, i.Type, d.CreatedOn

)

select * from (
    SELECT "Count",Item,Description,Type,ROW_NUMBER()  Over (PARTITION BY Name order by "Count" desc) AS RowNum, Name, CreatedOn
    FROM CustomerRank  
where CreatedOn > '2017-1-1 00:00:00'

) s where RowNum <6
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
WITH CustomerRank
AS
(SELECT 
    Count(*) AS "Count",
    d.Item, d.Description, Name, i.Type
FROM dbo.Inspection i
INNER JOIN dbo.Details d ON d.Inspection_Id = i.Id
INNER JOIN dbo.BuildingParts b ON b.Id = i.BuildingPart_Id
INNER JOIN dbo.Assessments a ON a.Id = b.AssessmentId
INNER JOIN dbo.Applications ap ON ap.Id = a.Application_Id
INNER JOIN dbo.Customers c ON c.Id = a.Customer_Id
where CreatedOn > '2017-1-1 00:00:00'
group by d.Item, d.Description, Name, i.Type
)
select * from (
    SELECT "Count",Item,Description,Type,ROW_NUMBER()  Over (PARTITION BY Name order by "Count" desc) AS RowNum, Name
    FROM CustomerRank  
) s where RowNum <6
```

The idea is that the `CreatedOn` column must be removed from the `GROUP BY` clause (because if you keep it there, we would get a different row for each value of the `CreatedOn` column).

Also, it's better to use JOIN-s and aliases for each table.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot. I'll get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: I managed to get it working. I appreciate you explaining about the CreatedOn Thingy.